# Mutate same session cookie in different loaders

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, remix, remix.run

In the case of a parent/child route structure, on initial page load, both loaders are called.
In the following example we use the same session (cookie based) in both of these loaders.

Both loaders have the request as a starting point and use that to get the cookie based session.
Obviously, we now have 2 instances of that cookie session which we are mutating.

This causes 2 problems:

1. By committing the session headers, you are only committing that 1 specific mutation, not both.
2. Because it's an initial page load and both loaders are called, we are setting the same Set-Cookie header twice with a different value, causing a race condition (?)

How can I manage the same session across multiple loaders and not set the cookie multiple times?

```js
const { getSession, commitSession } =
  createCookieSessionStorage({Path: '/'});

// /parent
export const loader = async ({ request }) => {
    const session = await getSession(request.headers.get('Cookie'));
    session.set('parent', 'parentValue');

    return json({}, {
        headers: new Headers({
            'Set-Cookie': await commitSession(session)
        })
    })
}

// /parent/child
export const loader = async ({ request }) => {
    const session = await getSession(request.headers.get('Cookie'));
    session.set('child', 'childValue');

    return json({}, {
        headers: new Headers({
            'Set-Cookie': await commitSession(session)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: What _path_ are you specifying when setting those cookies?

Comment: Path is '/' so the cookie gets applied to all routes (intended)

Comment: I wouldn't update session on loaders, but only on actions, since they are guaranteed to only have one active request. If you must update session in loaders, then I would choose something different than cookie backed sessions. Cookie only stores session id. That way there is only one place the data is stored.

Comment: The main reason is calling an external API on page load.
If this call fails, my thought was to `session.flash` a message onto the session, as we can then use that flash message in the component to display the failed API call to the user.

In case of a parent/child route structure you need to `session.flash` and commit the session in both loaders.

> I wouldn't update session on loaders

My use case seems to be a completely valid reason to update the session, unless I'm thinking along a wrong architectural path.

A non-cookie solution is overkill for displaying a simple error I think.